# Inserir dados em tabela com chave estrangeira

Tags: sql, sql-server

Sabendo que tenho uma tabela com os campos:

```
[ARQUIVO_GUID]
,[XARQUIVO]
,[TAG]
,[EXTENSAO]
,[URL]
,[IS_STREAM]

[ULT_ARQUIVO_VERSAO_GUID] FK
[TIPO_DE_ARQUIVO_GUID] FK
[DIRETORIO_GUID] FK
```

Os últimos 3 campos, são chaves estrangeiras para outras tabelas, como faço pra inserir dados na tabela *Arquivo*?

Comment: Você sabe quais são os `id`s das outras tabelas com os quais você tem que preencher essa query?

Comment: atualizei o esquema completo, nao tem nenhum dado insrido, quero inserir um arquivo, como ficaria o insert?

Comment: Você primeiro precisa inserir linhas nas tabelas `DIRETORIO`, `ARQUIVO_VERSAO` e `TIPO_DE_ARQUIVO` para então aproveitar os `id`s das linhas inseridas na tabela `ARQUIVO`.

Comment: se puder postar como resposta todos os inserts agradeceria muito, se não puder coloca so do arquivo mesmo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@WarLock, segue um exemplo:

```
using (var dbContext in new SeuDBContext()) {
    var arquivoVersao = new ARQUIVO_VERSAO();
    //Set das Propriedades do objeto arquivoVersao 

    var tipoArquivo = new TIPO_DE_ARQUIVO();
    //Set das Propriedades do objeto tipoArquivo 

    var diretorio = new DIRETORIO();
    //Set das Propriedades do objeto diretorio 

    var arquivo = new ARQUIVO();
    arquivo.DIRETORIO = diretorio;
    arquivo.TIPO_DE_ARQUIVO = tipoArquivo;
    arquivo.ARQUIVO_VERSAO = arquivoVersao;
    //Set das Propriedades de arquivo 

    dbContext.ARQUIVOS.Add(arquivo);
    dbContext.SaveChanges();
}
```

No SQL pode ser algo assim:

```
DECLARE @arquivoVersaoID as uniqueidentifier
DECLARE @tipoArquivoID as uniqueidentifier
DECLARE @diretorioID as uniqueidentifier

SET @arquivoVersaoID = NEWID();
SET @tipoArquivoID = NEWID();
SET @diretorioID = NEWID();

INSERT INTO ARQUIVO_VERSAO VALUES (@arquivoVersaoID, /*Demais propriedades*/);
INSERT INTO TIPO_DE_ARQUIVO VALUES (@tipoArquivoID, /*Demais propriedades*/);
INSERT INTO DIRETORIO VALUES (@diretorioID, /*Demais propriedades*/)
INSERT INTO ARQUIV VALUES (/*Demais propriedades*/, @arquivoVersaoID, @tipoArquivoID, @diretorioID)
```

Comment: Agradeço pela ajuda, mas eu to querendo o Sql mesmo normal

Comment: mas dessa forma ja insere dados em tudo?

Comment: mas como especifico a entrada de dados q nao entendi, o que to querendo  é preencher as tabelas com todos os dados.

Comment: valeu vou testar, no caso do entity que voce colocou la, como ficaria a entrada exatamente dos dados?

Comment: fiz uma atualização na resposta. neste caso você tera que inserir os dados em todas as tabelas, primeiro nas que são referenciadas e por ultimo na tabela Arquivos.

Comment: você setaria os dados normalmente, por exemplo: arquivo.ARQUIVO_GUID = Guid.NewGuid().

Comment: entendi, dai como faço para chamar o mesmo, ou seja fazer rodar e inserir os dados. Pode ser em um page load.

Comment: pode, não consigo ver muita logica em fazer uma carga de dados num page load.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no bate-papo](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20880/discussion-between-war-lock-and-tobymosque).

Comment: A ultima linha é dbContext.ARQUIVO.add ou dbContext.ARQUIVOS? pois arquivos não vai .

Comment: Isto vai depedende da modelagem do seu Contexto.
você ativou a pluralização dos nomes no momento da criação?

Comment: vai no chat pf...

Comment: Firewall não permite.

Comment: aqui deu um erro:  System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException: Erro ao atualizar as entradas. Consulte a exceção interna para obter detalhes. ---> System.Data.UpdateException:

Comment: fui pelo sql, e funcionou valeu.